# gapi’s auth popup closes immediately and fails with a 401 error

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I’m making a Chrome extension for Google Calendar where I need to authenticate to a Google Cloud Endpoints server. I use the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript for that, with the `gapi.auth.authorize` method:

```
var SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
];

function login() {
  gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(response) {
    if (response.code) {
      console.log("cannot auth: " + response.code + " (" + response.message + ")");
    } else {
      console.log("authed " + response.email);
    }
  });
}

gapi.auth.authorize({
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  scope: SCOPES.join(" "),
  immediate: immediate
}, login);
```

Now, **sometimes** it works, **sometimes** it doesn’t. In that case, a popup appears and is closed immediately, and the `response` object contains:

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials",
  "data": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "authError",
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
    }
  ],
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "data": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me find out the error’s source, or why it only happens occasionally. Note that another webapp uses the exact same code (client ID included) and works flawlessly.

Comment: for a chrome extension you should look at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

Comment: I can’t use `chrome.identity` since I need to share the token between the extension and the webapp, and `chrome.identity` requires another type of client ID

Comment: I've seen old comments that gapi isn't supported in Chrome Extensions. At the very least, it's an edge case for testing. You might want to reconsider. I have an app which happily uses chrome.identity in the extension, shared with gapi in the web app, and I don't have any sharing issues.

Comment: Don’t you have to manually craft requests to the API though? gapi seems way simpler to handle resources… Anyway, can you give me an example of a shared `chrome.identity` and gapi token? I actually tried that before, and couldn’t get it working.

Comment: I don't use the gapi client libs. I find it much easier to craft my own REST API calls. In my case I use AngularJS, so I have a $httpResource defined. A token is simply a string, so you can share it any way that suits your app.

Comment: Do you mind giving me a hint on how you manage to keep the user signed in without revealing your client secret?

Comment: I don't understand your question about client secret. There is no need  for the client secret in a javascript oauth flow. Did you mean client id?

Answer (score -1):

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  scope: SCOPES.join(" "),
  immediate: true
}, login);
```